# Re-calibrate Toshiba battery meter with Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, laptop, battery-life

I have a Toshiba U300 laptop. Back in the olden days (circa-2000) you could re-calibrate the battery meter from the BIOS when your battery was no longer reading accurately.

My battery was shot, so I bought a brand new one, however Windows 7 still seems to count down the battery life in at the same speed as the old one did. This time, when it alleged 0%, I turned the laptop back on and got another 90 minutes of life out of it, at 0%.

Is there a tool or utility for Toshiba laptops that can fix it back to being accurate? I've read the other threads on SU about cycling the battery but that just doesn't seem to do it in this case.

Update: After the last cycle, the battery meter now reads 100% but the indicator on the front of the laptop is still orange (indicating not fully charged)

Comment: Without providing a hardware-specific answer, you can use third-party utilities (e.g. [BatteryBar](http://osirisdevelopment.com/BatteryBar/)) to provide a much more accurate battery reading (including better wear-level, charge-time, and run-time estimates).

Answer (score 2):

You can try and remove the battery and turn the laptop on using the AC/DC adapter only. Then turn the laptop off, re-insert the battery and turn the laptop back on using battery power only and no charger plugged in. This may reset the system automatically so the laptop will read the correct amount of battery charge. Then fully charge the battery with charger. Once fully charged, remove the charger and let the battery drain on its own. Fully charge the battery and now see if it got right!

You could also check
[here](http://laptopbatterynews.com/2009/04/22/bios-says-to-recalibrate-my-laptop-battery/).

Answer (score 1):

I would contemplate contacting Toshiba for Technical support:

http://eu.computers.toshiba-europe.com/innovation/contact_toshiba.jsp

They should be able to provide you with the best advice regarding your laptop's situation.

If and when the situation is resolved I would install **BatteryCare** on your laptop, it is a software created to optimize the usage and performance of the modern laptop's battery

It monitors the battery's discharge cycles and helps increasing it's autonomy and improving its lifetime.

More information about it can be found here including contact info of the developer:

http://batterycare.net/en/index.html

Answer (score -1):

Do you have toshiba tools, namely microcode update checkers, installed in Windows 7? I'd guess original OS was Vista back in 2007.

There are three Toshiba **Satellite** U300 in Australia alone not to mention another ten in Americas, another twenty in Asia, and 30 more you can buy Europe....

And they share one common trait - NO SUPPORT FOR WINDOWS 7 AT ALL....

You might get some luck with one or both of their driver tools: http://www.csd.toshiba.com/cgi-bin/tais/support/jsp/bulletin.jsp?ct=SB&soid=2476028&ref=EV

Some of their BIOS updates allow to reset all parameters stored in BIOS, namely battery voltages(for which BIOS makes idea of %% of charge). Make sure you charge computer fully immediatly after, and discharge it fully before plugging back without letting it to sleep in the middle.

HP made a nice outline how to fully discharge battery to calibrate windows battery/shutdown meter after: http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?cc=us&lc=en&docname=c00817650